# How to configure a site-to-site vpn through strongswan

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I want to configure a site-to-site vpn using strongswan, my partner gaves me a domain encryption ip (kindly tell me what is this), and the parameters for ike and esp. They told me after finish configs I can test the connectivity using telnet.

I do an nmap scan to udp port 500,4500 and got a response of 'open|filtered', I also use the 'ike-scan' tool and receives 0 handshake and 0 notify.

I do some configs using strongswan swanctl but keeps getting 'IKE_SA failed, peer not responding'

Now I want to ask if the problem is in my configs, how to correctly config domain encryption ip, esp and ike parameters. And is nmap and ike-scan results indicates that the other side not accepting ike packets.